# Retrieving the image from database and displaying in web page in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, database, image, handler

I am trying to store the profile picture which the user uploads in a database and retrieve from the database and display in web page.I have successfully saved the image in database but I don't know how to retrieve it.I have tried to display but when I click the retrieve button nothing happens.

This is the code in Handler page and instead of retrieving the image based on Id I am trying to do it by passing the name of the user which will be on the welcome page.

```
     public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
       //passing name here
        if (context.Request.QueryString["name"] != null)
    {
        string csc = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(csc))
        {
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("RetrieveImage", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      //passing name
            SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@userName", context.Request.QueryString["name"]);
            com.Parameters.Add(p1);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["image"]);
            dr.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
     }
         else
         {
             context.Response.Write("No Image Found");
         }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
     }
```

I have created a stored procedure which accepts username and gives image.Stored procedure name is "RetrieveImage"
This is the button click event.On clicking the button "RetrieveImage" it calls handler and passes value as "name"which then calls stored procedure and displays image

```
      protected void RetrieveImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        string csc = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(csc))
        {
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("RetrieveImage", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@userName", WelcomeUsername.Text);
            com.Parameters.Add(p1);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
        ImageDisp.ImageUrl = "~/ImagePage.ashx?name=" + WelcomeUsername.Text;
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

When I run the page I am not getting any error but when I click the button nothing happens.I am new to .Net .Please help.!! Thanks in advance

Comment: Try setting the context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

Comment: I tried but same thing happens @Aman Baloch

Comment: Are you saving the image in the bytes...

Comment: Can you debug and see if anything is being returned from Database? something like var image = (byte[])dr["image"]; and then check the content of image